# I am getting the access_token from the Instagram login API using nodejs express, please look at the error

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

I am currently implementing Instagram login using the express framework of nodejs.
First of all, I succeeded in getting the code by completing the test user authentication. However, when I use the code to get the access_token, an error occurs as shown below.

```
"{"error_type": "OAuthException", 
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"
}"
```

So, to see if the redirect_uri is different, I also checked my app in the developer center, and there was no typo.

The source to get the access_token from.

```js
  const authorizeCode = req.query?.code;
   if(authorizeCode){
    try{
      request.post({
        url : `${API_URL}/oauth/access_token`
        ,method : 'POST'
        ,formData:{
          'code':authorizeCode
          ,client_id
          ,client_secret
          ,'grant_type':'authorization_code'
          ,'redirect_uri':'https://localhost/auth/'
        }
      }, (error, response, body) =>{
          console.log(body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
        }   
      });
      console.log(response.ok)
    }catch(e){
      console.error(e);
    }  
   }else{
    const {error,error_reason,error_description} = req.query;
    console.error(`error : ${error} \n reason : ${error_reason} \n description : ${error_description}`);
   }
```

This is a valid OAuth redirect URI set in the Facebook Developer Center My Apps.

[image]

Comment: Additional verification result - The redirect uri was confirmed to match, and it was confirmed as an error caused by a different value of the client secret.

Comment: Per FB documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow#confirm), `grant_type` parameter isn't mentioned for `/oauth/access_token` endpoint, try removing it. Consider also adding the code generating URL for `/dialog/oauth` to your question, perhaps we can find some disparities there.